# How many options are there for dividing 200 pennies into 3 bags?

Tags: combinatorics

Ill be glad if you could help me solve this one.

How many options are there for dividing same 200 pennies into 3 same bags?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: I don't know how start solving it...thats why I asked.

Comment: it's the same as the number of non-negative integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3=200$.

Comment: @Jeremy, so what is the solution for 3 different bags?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yeah

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Let's start with three different bags.  Then we have a standard [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem, the number of ways to solve $x_1+x_2+x_3=200$  We can't have all three variables the same, as $3$ does not divide into $200.$  The solutions with two variables the same need to be divided by $3$, as there are three orders for them.  How many of them are there?  The rest have to be divided by $6$ because all the variables are different.